Can you opt to fail a saving throw?
Can you opt to not roll a saving throw (or more generally a check against DC), thereby automatically failing it? For example, if one of your allies wants to shove you to reposition you, you normally make a saving throw to avoid the effect. But what if you actually do not want to avoid the effect? Can you decide to not resist it, and let yourself be shoved?

I'm very interested in the answer, but I think it's a bit messier: it's not just choosing to fail a saving throw, it's choosing to let a check against a DC based on your statistics succeed. Shove/reposition don't roll saves, they're just checks.

what does opt mean/stand for?

@ElvinaMoonlight It's just a normal English word. Opt on dictionary.com: to make a choice; choose (usually followed by for).

As an optional rule, you may make the effect one degree worse
Bestiary 3 contains an unusual creature, the gliminal, which can kill you with excessive positive healing. To avoid this fate, characters may wish to allow their allies to damage them. A sidebar accompanying the gliminal explains how this might be adjudicated:

There aren't default rules for a creature choosing to be hit (to avoid exploding from a gliminal's healing), but you can allow an ally to improve their outcome by one degree of success against a willing target or allow the target to worsen the result of their saving throw by one step.

The Pathfinder Society FAQ makes this the official rule for organized play:

Can I willingly fail a save if my ally is attempting to use an item or ability to benefit me?
Pathfinder Society uses the optional rules published with the [g]liminal on page [114] of Bestiary 3 for this situation

(The original ruling misspelled the creature name and pointed to the wrong page number.)
I have seen this rule in action at several PFS tables and it seems more reasonable than simply allowing an auto-fail. The wizard with -1 Strength cannot necessarily move the kineticist who is legendary in Fortitude. Note that if you are using this to break a grab, you will need to roll versus the grabbing effect's DC, which means that your grabbed ally cannot "lean in" to it.

I'd say that there are active and passive saving rolls.
When you got poisoned and save against the venom, you are saving pasively, and you have not word on the result, as it's your body and your metabolism who is trying to save you.
On the other hand, when you try to avoid consciounsly being hit by an area effect spell, or resisting mind influence, you are somewhat actively trying to avoid something. Then you definitively could just fail voluntarily.
